# Create Dataframe based on two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to create a dataframe based on 2 existing dataframes that extracts values based on a dummy (which is common to both of them), in particular if the dummy is 1, then extract from dataframe a, if the dummy is 0, then extract from dataframe b). This is what they look like:

a:

```
var1   var2    var3   dummy
ax1     ay1    az1    1
ax2     ay2    az1    0
ax3     ay3    az1    1
```

b:

```
var1   var2    var3   dummy
bx1     by1    bz1    1
bx2     by2    bz1    0
bx3     by3    bz1    1
```

My goal is to obtain a new dataframe that extracts based on the dummy like this:

c:

```
var1   var2    var3   dummy
ax1     ay1    az1    1
bx2     by2    bz1    0
ax3     ay3    az1    1
```

I am working on a cumbersome loop right now, but I am wondering if there is a simple way within the apply family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I would just use a simple rbind with conditionals:

```
new_df <- rbind(a[a$dummy == 1,], b[b$dummy == 0,])
```

That should output:

```
var1   var2    var3   dummy
ax1     ay1    az1    1
bx2     by2    bz1    0
ax3     ay3    az1    1
```

As a side note, you very very rarely have to use loops in R. Odds are, if you are using a loop there is a better, more R way to do things.

Comment: Note that this will not work for no common dummies in `a` and `b` for exemple if the value in `a` is `0` and the value in `b` is `1`.

Comment: @ANG I believe OP wants to exclude the cases you just described

Comment: Thank ANG for thinking of that case. leeum is indeed right, that the dummy is common, that is a=0 and b=1 will not happen in my case but thank you for illustrating that below. I have added that to my personal cheat sheet, I am sure I will need it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Try this subsetting strategy.

```
sa <- as.logical(a$dummy) # use this to subset a
sb <- as.logical(1 - a$dummy) # and this to subset b
c <- rbind(a[sa, ], b[sb, ])
# Output
#  var1 var2 var3 dummy
#1  ax1  ay1  az1     1
#3  ax3  ay3  az1     1
#2  bx2  by2  bz1     0

# Data
a <- structure(list(var1 = c("ax1", "ax2", "ax3"), var2 = c("ay1", 
"ay2", "ay3"), var3 = c("az1", "az1", "az1"), dummy = c(1, 0, 
1)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "dummy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
b <- structure(list(var1 = c("bx1", "bx2", "bx3"), var2 = c("by1", 
"by2", "by3"), var3 = c("bz1", "bz1", "bz1"), dummy = c(1, 0, 
1)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "dummy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```